# auth0 + angular + spring question: getting info workflow

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, jwt, auth0

SITUATION
I'm testing out auth0 and I'm confused about the data that gets sent back. This could just be a fundamental misunderstanding of JWTs since I've always just used sessions.

The data I get back from the claims are below.

```
{
    sub=auth0|redacted, 
    aud=[redacted, redacted], 
    azp=redacted, 
    scope=openid profile email, 
    iss=redacted, 
    exp=2022-07-17T23:44:01Z, 
    iat=2022-07-16T23:44:01Z
}
```

I get the sub, which is the auth source and the ID. I also have the bearer token. I can call the API to get the complete user information from [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info) but I don't want to call the API just to get the email.

PROBLEM
I want to have a user object that I can associate with objects (i.e. if a user saves a form, I want to associate the user who created the form). Since they can auth from multiple sources (auth0 or google), I can't just assume that I can use the sub ID that I get from the JWT because I have to account for the scenario that they're authing into the app in different ways.

Do I really need to call the API just to get the email, and then search my database for the email? I only need to call the API to get the email if I don't have the sub ID saved into the database, which I can do every time they use an auth-type for the very first time. That just seems so wonky that I'm assuming I'm going about this totally wrong.

Is there another unique ID that I can use other than the email?

Am I viewing this completely wrong? I need a custom User object within my application so I can have an audit trail or pull back documents specific to a user. Is there a better way to think about this when using JWTs, specifically from auth0?

INFO
Repos I'm using:

https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/spa_angular_typescript_hello-world/tree/basic-authentication

https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/api_spring-mvc_java_hello-world/tree/basic-authorization

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Just add a rule and it'll add the email to the claims. Here's the step-by-step.

https://community.auth0.com/t/can-i-add-email-address-to-the-access-token-when-calling-an-api/70163

> Hi @trondhindenes,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to the Auth0 Community.
>
> Is there any way to affect the data in the access token retrived here?
> const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0(); Can I somehow indicate
> that I’d like to add the user’s emai added to that token?
>
> Yes! I recommend using the Add email to access token rule to add the
> user’s email address to the access token. Navigate to your Dashboard >
> Auth0Pipeline > Rules > Create and select the Add email to access
> token rule.
>
> For the complete list of User Object Properties, take a look at this
> documentation: https://auth0.com/docs/rules/user-object-in-rules
>
> After doing so, you can use the Access Token to access your API that
> contains information about the user’s email address in the payload.
>
> Please let me know if this addresses your questions.
>
> Thank you.